# Games minimize to task bar

Tags: windows, crash, internet-explorer-9, directx

Ever since installing Internet Explorer 9, several my games in Steam either crash (for instance Burnout Paradise) or insist on minimizing to the task bar (for instance GTA IV). In the latter case, they seem to be running, but it appears some other window is stealing focus, essentially switching out of the game.

I'm on Windows Vista Business with SP2 and use Microsoft Security Essentials and have the exact same behavior on my Windows 7 Professional with SP1 laptop. There's nothing noteworthy installed or running while launching a game from Steam.

I recall reading that IE9 installs a new version of DirectX, so perhaps this is causing problems. Is this a known problem and is there a solution, or am I wrong about this?

Comment: If something solved it, put that as an answer so others will know how to fix this.

Comment: I don't think that uninstalling IE9 is really "the solution", but I'll post it nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure enough, after uninstalling IE9 and rebooting, resolved this for me.

I tried on my laptop: exactly the same resolution. There's no doubt in my mind that this is related to IE9.

This isn't really a solution, because IE9 shouldn't cause problems with gaming. It just so happened to be that I noticed the problems directly after installing it, and they disappeared after removal.

Comment: It actually is a solution since it fixed the problem you were having.

Comment: True, but the follow-up question would then be how to be able to game and use IE9 on the same machine.

Comment: I've found something of a hacky solution [posted on the GTA Forums](http://www.gtaforums.com/index.php?showtopic=459257). I haven't tried this, but others suggest it may work.